# Android: sendto failed: EBADF (Bad file number)

Tags: java, android

I'm seeing an error message `EBADF` after my system has been running for a while on Android:

```
05-04 19:11:33.157 17688-18012/? W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: sendto failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
05-04 19:11:33.157 17688-18012/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.sendtoBytes(Native Method)
05-04 19:11:33.157 17688-18012/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.sendto(Posix.java:176)
05-04 19:11:33.157 17688-18012/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:278)
05-04 19:11:33.157 17688-18012/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:513)
```

The error occurs when I'm trying to write a byte to a `DataOutputStream`, but I don't understand what the error means.

Comment: If you use the {} button around code text (or indent each line four spaces) then it will be formatted correctly.

Comment: When you are writing/editing your comments in Stack Overflow, there are buttons at the top which allow you to apply formatting. See the help pages for more information.